# Concatenating strings using foreach

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to make a generated random characters. I'm concatenating the values of **$char_type** using foreach loop but it doesn't show anything. Here's my code:

```
    public function randomizer($range, $type) {
     $strtester = '';
     $char_type = array('alp_sm' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                        'alp_cs' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                        'num'    => '0123456789',
                        'sp'     => '!@#$%^&*()');

     if(is_array($type)) {
         foreach($type as $row) {
             if(in_array($row, $char_type)) {
                 $strtester .= $char_type[$row];
             }
         }
     }
     print_r($strtester); exit();
     $seed = str_split($strtester);
     shuffle($seed);
     $generated_string = '';
     foreach (array_rand($seed, $range) as $k) $generated_string .= $seed[$k];

     return $generated_string;
    }
```

**Update:**
What i want to get from `$strtester` is for example I want `$char_type` *alp_sm* and *alp_cs* then the `$strtester` will get `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Thank you in advance

Comment: what are you passing as `$range` and `$type`?

Comment: @Mureinik `$range` is for the number of characters to be generated and `$type` will be the type of the generated code.

Comment: I understand what they mean. I'm asking about the concrete values you passed that gave you the erroneous output.

Comment: @Mureinik this are the values `randomizer(5, array("alp_sm"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `if(in_array($row, $char_type)) {` to `if(array_key_exists($row, $char_type)) {` and then try

```
    function randomizer($range, $type) {
         $strtester = '';
         $char_type = array('alp_sm' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                            'alp_cs' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                            'num'    => '0123456789',
                            'sp'     => '!@#$%^&*()');

        if(is_array($type)) {
            foreach($type as $row) {
                if(array_key_exists($row, $char_type)) {
                    $strtester .= $char_type[$row];
                }
            }
        }

        $seed = str_split($strtester);
        shuffle($seed);
        $generated_string = '';
        foreach (array_rand($seed, $range) as $k) 
            $generated_string .= $seed[$k];
        return $generated_string;
    }

    $res =  randomizer(5, array("alp_sm"));
    print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
if(in_array($row, $char_type)) {
```

You're actually looking for if the key exists, not whether the array contains that string - you need to use isset:

```
if(is_array($type)) {
    foreach($type as $row) {
        if(isset($char_type[$row]) {
            $strtester .= $char_type[$row];
        }
    }
}
print_r($strtester); exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this but I think this might be the easiest one to work around

```
function randomizer($range, $type) {
     $char_type = array('alp_sm' => range('a','z'),
                        'alp_cs' => range('A','Z'),
                        'num'    => range(0,9),
                        'sp'     => ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')']);
    shuffle($char_type[$type[0]]);                    
    $generated_string = implode(array_slice($char_type[$type[0]],0,$range));
    return $generated_string;
}

$res =  randomizer(5, array("alp_sm"));
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for `is_array`. It checks whether the variable is an array

```
$strtester = '';
if(is_array($type)) {
    foreach($type as $row) {
        if(isset($char_type[$row]) {
            $strtester .= $char_type[$row];
        }
    }
}
```

refer the [PHP Docs for is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Comment: actually i did :) the problem was in `if(in_array($row, $char_type)) {` as @HorusKol said